# How do I take a file name and an int from the terminal and pass them into a c program to be used as parameters?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu

I need to write a program that reads through a given text file from the terminal and counts the number of times a given number from the command line occurs in the text file.

Example `test.txt` file:

```
"here is your class CSC 1010"
```

Running the program:

```
$./countD test.txt 1
'1' appeared 2 times
```

Comment: You need to use  command line arguments in C. But what have you tried out so far?

Comment: The basic function from the standard library is `getopt`. See: `man 3 getopt`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

1. It takes command line arguments from main by `int main(int

   argc,char* argv[])` and opens the file which is gotten by the command line arguments.
2. " argc " gives the number of arguments needed and gives an error if they are not as required.
3. atoi converts the number taken as string to integer.
4. `getc()` is used to iterate through the file.
5. `fscanf` takes the integers from the file and stores them in num.
6. a while loop is used to get the digits of each numbers and count the number of ones.

   ```
   #include<stdio.h>
   #include<stdlib.h>

   int main(int argc,char* argv[])
   {
       int c=0;
       if(argc != 3)
       {
           printf("usage: ./a.out file number\n");
           return 1;
       }

   char* file = argv[1];
   int n = atoi(argv[2]);
   FILE *inptr = fopen(file,"read");
   if(inptr == NULL)
   {
       printf("error\n");
       return 2;
   }
   int num=0;

   int ch = getc(inptr); //to get to the end of file
   while(ch != EOF)
   {
       fscanf(inptr,"%d",&num);//scanning numbers one by one
       while(num!=0)           //as it was given by you in your example 
       {                       //you require the appearances of digit 1  
           int d = num%10;     //1 can also appear multiple times in a 
           if(d == n)          //single number and hence i had to extract 
           {                   //the digits of the number also
               c++;
           }
           num/=10;
       }

       ch = getc(inptr);
   }

   printf("'%d' appeared %d times\n",n,c);

   fclose(inptr);
   return 0;
   ```

   }

Comment: Could you please make a briefly explanation of your code? That will improve the understanding of your answer. Please, read about [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The proper prototypes for the `main` function are:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
```

(you will also see it written with the equivalent `char *argv[]`)

or

```
int main (void)
```

The first case provides an integer argument count `argc` that holds the number of arguments passed to your program. The arguments are indexes to and array of pointers to strings held in `argv` where the next entry after the last is a *sentinel* `NULL`. The program name is always the first argument (with the `zero` index) in the list, next all commands passed to the program on the command line.

The second case for `main` (`int main (void)`) makes explicit that no arguments are passed to the program.

In your case, you simply want to take two arguments, (1) the filename to read from and (2) the character to search for, can both be handled very easily. The first argument can be used to open the file, and the second can be use as a search char to check against each character in the file. You can use a *ternary* operator to provide default values for both, e.g.

```
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;
    int c, srchc = argc > 2 ? *argv[2] : '1', n = 0;
```

Above, `argv[1]` is used as the filename (or it will default to reading from `stdin`, the first character in `argv[2]` is your search character.

Next you need do little more than **validate** the file is opened for reading, e.g.

```
     if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }
```

and then loop over every character in the file keeping count of the number of times your `srchc` matches the current char, e.g.

```
    while ((c = fgetc (fp)) != EOF)  /* read from file until EOF found */
        if (c == srchc)     /* compare srchc against each char in file */
            n++;
```

Putting it altogether, you can do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;
    int c, srchc = argc > 2 ? *argv[2] : '1', n = 0;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    while ((c = fgetc (fp)) != EOF)  /* read from file until EOF found */
        if (c == srchc)     /* compare srchc against each char in file */
            n++;

    printf ("'%c' appeared %d times\n", srchc, n);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/cscfile.txt
here is your class CSC 1010
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/charinfile dat/cscfile.txt 1
'1' appeared 2 times
```

Look things over and let me know if you have any further questions.